# Кнопка перключения стилей

Tags: javascript, css

Подскажите как на JavaScript сделать скрипт чтоб он менял стиль страницы с ночного на дневной. С HTML и CSS я справился, а вот кнопку переключения стилей не понимаю как.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для переключения между таблицами стилей можно менять значение атрибута `href` текущей таблицы, например так:

```
document.getElementById('stylesheet').href = 'dark.css'
```

[Пример](https://jsfiddle.net/ax93812q/1/)

Или переключение тем можно сделать изменением атрибута `class` верхнего контейнера, например, `body`.

```js
document.getElementById('toggle').onclick = function () {
  document.body.classList.toggle('dark');
}
```

```css
body {
}

body.dark {
  background: #000;
}

body.dark button {
  background: #000;
  border-color: #fff;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<button id="toggle">Сменить тему</button>
```

Comment: @komsonavt, если нужно менять и верстку страницы, опишите эти изменения

Comment: У меня есть две таблицы стилей, нарисованы и отрихтованы. Я хочу с помощью кнопки переключаться между ними?

Comment: @komsonavt дополнил ответ